# Figuring out whether `cin.getline()` succeeds

Tags: c++, validation, file-io, cin, getline

Here's the basic code snippet:

```
while (true)
{
  cin.getline(str, STRSIZE);
  if (str[0] == '\n') { break; }
}
```

Essentially, when the user inputs just a lonely return key, the loop is **supposed** to end.
Of course, this code doesn't work, because the `\n` is flushed, and never ends up in `str` to verify that a lonely `\n` was entered. I'm not curious why this doesn't work; I know why.

> **How can you verify that a lonely `\n` was entered, hence exiting the `while-loop`?**

---

I know one can do the following:

```
while (cin >> str);
```

However:

- `>>` only takes one word at a time
- In my actual code, a `for-loop` is used, rather than a `while-loop`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If `cin.getline()` fails to read a line, `cin` will be in a state of error.

You can use:

```
while (cin.getline(str, STRSIZE))
{
   if ( str[0] == '\0' ) { break; }

   // Use str
}
```

Comment: Oh, so when I call `cin.getline()`, `str` will be set to `\0`, and not garbage that `str` had before the call?

Comment: @SirJony, that's sort of correct. `str` will be set to an empty string, not `\0`.

Comment: What's the difference? By the way, I'm using `char []`, not `string`. I apologize for not making that clear.

Comment: @SirJony, `\0` can be the value of `char`, not a string. It can be the value of `str[0]` but not that of `str`. Subtle but important difference.

Comment: Oh, yes of course. I meant `str[0] == \0`, not `str == \0`.